# XPath to identify the elements from the list having none of the child elements with a particular value

Tags: xpath

My problem statement is to identify the films from the list in which a specific actor has not worked on.

e.g., I want to identify the films in which `"Actor1"` has not worked on.

The XPATH which I am using is returning all the films in which at least there is one actor other than the `"Actor1"`.

XPATH: `//film[.//actor/name[not(text()='Actor1')]]`

XML Input:

```
<list>
    <!-- Film1 -->
    <film>
        <name>Film1</name>
        <duration>3</duration>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor1</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor2</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </actor>
    </film>
    <!-- Film2 -->
    <film>
        <name>Film2</name>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor3</name>
            <age>34</age>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor1</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor4</name>
            <age>26</age>
        </actor>
    </film>
    <!-- Film3 -->
    <film>
        <name>Film3</name>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor2</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor5</name>
            <age>16</age>
        </actor>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor6</name>
            <age>5</age>
        </actor>
    </film>
    <!-- Film4 -->
    <film>
        <name>Film4</name>
        <duration>1</duration>
        <actor>
            <name>Actor1</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </actor>
    </film>
</list>
```

EXPECTED: Only node for `"Film3"` should be returned

ACTUAL: XPath result

```
<film>
    <name>Film1</name>
    <duration>3</duration>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor1</name>
        <age>40</age>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor2</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </actor>
</film>
<film>
    <name>Film2</name>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor3</name>
        <age>34</age>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor1</name>
        <age>40</age>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor4</name>
        <age>26</age>
    </actor>
</film>
<film>
    <name>Film3</name>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor2</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor5</name>
        <age>16</age>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor6</name>
        <age>5</age>
    </actor>
</film>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath "means" *return `film` node if it has **at least one** `name` decdendant which text is not `'Actor1'`*. As long as `film` has `name` descendant with text `'Actor2'` or `'Actor3'`or whatever your XPath will return that node

Try this one to get required output:

```
//film[not(actor/name='Actor1')]
```